# Does changing one's hostname also clear the root's bash history?

Tags: bash, debian, command-history

I'm asking because mine is strangely short and I definitely didn't clear them. However I tried changing my username (because I got some errors which I thought were due to my hostname; tried to view the history to see how I did that to change it back) and I'm not sure if that could have caused the history to be cleared?

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE and $HISTSIZE variable is set to its default value.

(In the root history there are also 2 commands which I can't remember having executed: `filemanager /var/mail/root` and `texteditor /etc/nsswitch.conf` [for which I'd like to view diffs using etckeeper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384363/how-can-i-view-diffs-or-at-least-older-versions-of-specific-files-with-etckeeper).)

Comment: You could check the timestamp on file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to try determine *when* the mysterious editing took place.  Someone having cleared the root bash history suggests the server may have been compromised.

Comment: @steve I don't know whether it was edited. I probably just forgot about opening it. The modification date says 3 August. Well if the history is kind of lost when changing one's hostname it wouldn't require cleaning. I'm just pretty sure that I executed more commands as root than shown after running `sudo -i` and `history` (if that really shows all the root history). It's not a server.

Comment: do you normally use the `filemanager` and `texteditor` commands?  that's fairly uncommon IME - most people have a preferred file manager and/or text editor and run them directly rather than via a symlink or alias, or use a short alias to reduce the amount of typing.

Comment: @cas Sorry for not making that clear enough: it's the filemanager and texteditor that I use. I probably opened them and forgot about it (and about how the contents of that nsswitch file looked like). I had plenty of problems with name resolution earlier so I would be interested in any changes to nsswitch.