# How can I view diffs or at least older versions of specific files with etckeeper?

Tags: debian, git, diff, version-control, etckeeper

So I'm using [etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) on my machine running Debian 9.1 with KDE and would like to view diffs (or if that isn't yet implemented: past versions) of specific files. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, with `etckeeper`, `/etc` is a git repository, so you can use git tools to view its contents (and the changes). For example, you can use [`gitk`](https://tracker.debian.org/gitk) (after installing it) to browse the repository’s history, and if you want to focus on a specific file, you can specify it on the command line:

```
cd /etc
gitk apt/sources.list &
```

Since you’re a KDE user, you might find [`qgit`](https://tracker.debian.org/qgit) nicer.

Comment: Will use that in the future. It didn't work now as I didn't initialize the database as I thought it would do that on its own - especially as I noticed how several .git folders were created automatically via some other tool. I didn't know it needed to be configured first because there was nothing on its website nor a popup / wizard after installation. But I guess people are used to reading the man pages for tools.

Comment: It’s generally useful to read at least the [`README`](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/README/) (which in this case is quite good).

Comment: `gitk` looks like a great tool to use w/`etckeeper`. I wondered if there was a CLI-only version available as my Raspberry Pi is the "zero graphics"/Lite distro. There are some promising ideas covered in this [thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361019/viewing-full-version-tree-in-git); this one in [particular :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18287861/5395338)

Comment: @Seamus in terminals I use `tig`.

Answer (score 2):

I just use `git log` and `git show` or `git diff`.  e.g.

```
# git log --oneline /etc/squid/squid.conf
907df30 saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
a612769 daily autocommit
6d45b99 saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
0f21707 daily autocommit
9a95a9b saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
b2518f4 daily autocommit
338b4a7 daily autocommit
862d5e6 committing changes in /etc after apt run
ff6a8fd daily autocommit
2d64d79 saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
7e3bb0e Initial commit


# git diff a612769 907df30 /etc/squid/squid.conf
diff --git a/squid/squid.conf b/squid/squid.conf
index 0e08217..e630ed9 100644
--- a/squid/squid.conf
+++ b/squid/squid.conf
@@ -7876,9 +7876,3 @@ forwarded_for off
 #  not all I/O types supports large values (eg on Windows).
 #Default:
 # Use operating system limits set by ulimit.
-
-#httpd_accel_host virtual
-#httpd_accel_port 80
-#httpd_accel_with_proxy on
-#httpd_accel_uses_host_header on
-
```

If I wanted the full contents of a specific revision of a file, I'd use `git ls-tree` (to get the sha1 of the file blob) and `git cat-file` to output it.  e.g.

```
# git cat-file blob "$(git ls-tree a612769 /etc/squid/squid.conf | 
                       awk '{print $3}')" > /tmp/squid.conf.a612769
```