# Is it possible to view past versions of files after a renewed etckeeper init?

Tags: debian, sudo, etckeeper

So as the terminal was telling me that /etc wasn't a git repository after running `git status` and `gitk resolv.conf &` I made a mistake and ran `sudo etckeeper init` and `sudo etckeeper commit "Initial version"` which I already ran earlier before realizing that the terminal was printing out this misleading info(!) only when not using `sudo`.
Now I'd like to know whether (and if so how) I can view changes to files before I reran the init command. Are they still stored somewhere in a way that I could retrieve them? I'm using Debian 9.1 with KDE.

Comment: What is the output of `git reflog | head` (as root in `/etc` of course)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  `etckeeper init` is basically harmless, and it does not affect existing git history.

Comment: But then how can I view changes to files? Via [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384363/how-can-i-view-diffs-or-at-least-older-versions-of-specific-files-with-etckeeper/384368#384368) question I learned that `sudo gitk resolv.conf &` was a good way for doing so but it only shows "Initial commit" even though the file has been changed.

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm did you run `etckeeper uninit` as well?  (It prompts for confirmation, unless you pass `-f`).

Comment: Nope. I never ran that command.